# Empty extra button created in chrome extension popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So I have an extremely simple popup for a chrome extension that has a single button in the html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Extension popup</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="dashboard">Button<button>
</body>
</html>
```

So it is only supposed to show one button but a second empty button is also shown. Inspecting the popup shows that there is indeed another button.
[image]

I am mostly wondering whether anyone knows what is going on here?

Comment: Typo: duplicate `<button>` tag.

Comment: Oh my god... I didn't notice that..